# Chrome Extension Inject Script into Popup with Blank URL

Tags: google-chrome-extension, popup

I'm building a versatile extension with the permissions for `*://*/*` because the user needs to be able to configure which sites to run on. The extension injects scripts into the matched tabs, but it fails for certain `popup` tabs.

A good example of this behavior is the presentation notes for a Google Presentation.

After running `chrome.tabs.executeScript` given one of these popup tabs (tabs in popup windows), `chrome.runtime.lastError` states:

> Cannot access contents of url "". Extension manifest must request permission to access this host.

There's nothing that I can see which mentions a blank URL, but I checked the tab object and it does indeed have a blank URL:

```json
{
  active: true,
  height: 580,
  highlighted: true,
  id: 882,
  incognito: false,
  index: 0,
  pinned: false,
  selected: true,
  status: "complete",
  title: "Speaker Notes - ... - Google Slides",
  url: "",
  width: 730,
  windowId: 884
}
```

How can I request permission to execute scripts inside this type of tab/window? Do I need to figure out what window created the popup and interact with the window from the context of the parent window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is a [known issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=77947).

Comment: Hm, consider this: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=76429 and the fact that `<all_urls>` instead of `*://*/*` should have access

Comment: Not posting the second part as an answer unless you confirm it's working.

Comment: I tried changing it to `<all_urls>` a couple days ago but it still didn't work. However, looking at that issue it looks like I have to specify `match_about_blank` and wait for Chrome 37. Does that sound correct?

Comment: It does, but I guess only RobW can tell for sure.